# How To Handle Kaltura session connection after reloading the page or the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, kaltura

I'm developping an application that required kaltura athentification.I used Kaltura "client.session.start" to get my KS and media content.
My problem is that i have to reathenificate everytime i reload the page or close the browser.

I thought about cookies to save the session data on the client side (browser) but i don't know if i have to create them by nodejs midelwares like (client-sessions, cookies parser,cookie-session...)or the kaltura session provides another way to keep the connection on (nothing mentioned in kaltura documentations).Or i have to create sipmle cookie with javascript. if the answer is using cookies  what data should i add inside them? and how can I use it after that.
 thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the session on the backend every time the page is loaded.
You can use the `generateSessionV2` method that will create the KS without doing an HTTP request to Kaltura.

See example here: https://knowledge.kaltura.com/understanding-kaltura-application-framework-kaf

Keep in mind that each Kaltura session has an expiration time (default is 24 hours).

Comment: I think i already did that by login through a session with "client.session.start(print_ks, secret, userId, type, partnerId, expiry, privileges)". BUT I don't know how to tel the browser it is the same session.IN another hand in the link you gived me they talk about Ifram..so do you think this is tha way to do it by loading an Ifram ?sorry it is not so clear for me. thank you once again for your help

Comment: Why do you need to keep the same session?

Comment: because when i reload the page on the browser i have to authenticate again so i would like to keep the session on instead of typing my credentials every time